# How do I break out of a recursion in C?

Tags: c, recursion, cryptarithmetic-puzzle

I'm still a newbie in programming, so please tolerate my poor syntax and logic if any were bad. I've been writing a cryptarithmetic puzzle solver in C. It reads 3 words from the user, calculates their value and prints them to screen. (e.g `send+more=money` -> `9567+1085=10652`)

I tried something similar to permutation algorithm. It can do the calculations but for some inputs, results are printed multiple times:

[image: Example output]

How can I modify my code so the first time the printf commands under `if (n1+n2==n3)` are processed recursion ends and the program returns to the `main` function?

```
/* Swaps the two elements of an array. */
void swap(int v[], int i, int j) {
    int t;
    t = v[i];
    v[i] = v[j];
    v[j] = t;
}

/* Solves the Cryptarithmetic puzzle. */
int solve(int v[], int n, int i, char s1[], char s2[], char s3[], char letters[]) {
    int k, m, j, t = 0, power, n1 = 0, n2 = 0, n3 = 0;
    if (i == n) {
        /*....some codes that 
         * calculate the value of each input word.....*/

        /*This part verifies the values and if they are correct, prints them to screen*/
        if (n1 + n2 == n3) {
            printf("found!\n");
            printf("\n%s :  %6d\n", s1, n1);
            printf("%s :  %6d\n", s2, n2);
            printf("%s :  %6d\n", s3, n3);
        }
    } else
        for (j = i; j < n; j++) {
            swap(v, i, j);
            solve(v, n, i + 1, s1, s2, s3, letters);
            swap(v, i, j);
        }
}
```

Comment: Since you defined your function as type `int`, you need to `return` a value of type `int`. Returning `1` if nothing else to show success, or `0` if an error is encountered at a minimum.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I tried putting a `return 1;` after `printf ("%s :  %6d\n", s3 , n3);` but nothing changed.

Comment: You put the `return` where you need to `terminate` the recursion. Like what happens after `i==n` or what happens after your finish the `else for` loop?. Be aware that after a `return` in a recursive functions, the function will still iterate backwards as it `backs out of the levels of recursion`. How do you know when you are done processing? Put the return there...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three changes are needed.  First, you need to return something once you solved it:

```
    printf ("%s : %6d\n", s3 , n3);
    return 1;
```

Next, you need to check the return value when you recurse, and stop if you found a solution:

```
    if (solve (v, n, i+1,s1,s2,s3,letters))
        return 1;
```

Last, if you don't find a solution, you need to return 0:

```
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `setjmp()/longjmp()`. For this you need to:

```
#include <setjmp.h>
```

then a global variable:

```
jmp_buf env;
```

Then in main (or wherever you call your recursive function) you do:

```
if(!setjmp(env)) recursiveSolve();
```

and then when you find the solution:

```
if(solutionFound) longjmp(env, 1);
```

and it will return to main like nothing happened - but your solution found.

Comment: Using the 70 ton press to squash a fly! `setjmp()` / `longjmp()` is not to be used lightly.  Better make `solve()` return a success indicator and test that upon recursive calls. I also gives the initial caller a simple success indicator.

Comment: @chqrlie an exception mechanism would be the 70 ton press, `longjmp()` is the lightest thing in this case when one doesn't want to do like you said (the right way) for whatever reasons.